# mavros with serial connection

Tags: mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I try get imu_pub topics. Connection via USB. I launch:

```
roslaunch mavros apm2.launch
```

and get

> [ INFO] [1423223050.794198448]: FCU
> URL: /dev/ttyACM0:115200 [ INFO]
> [1423223050.794370090]: device:
> /dev/ttyACM0 @ 115200 bps [ INFO]
> [1423223050.794872555]: GCS bridge
> disabled [ INFO]
> [1423223050.799750201]: Plugin [alias
> 3dr_radio] blacklisted [ INFO]
> [1423223050.858428577]: Plugin Command
> [alias command] loaded and initialized
> [ INFO] [1423223050.858484604]: Plugin
> [alias ftp] blacklisted [ INFO]
> [1423223050.858500013]: Plugin [alias
> global_position] blacklisted [ INFO]
> [1423223050.861491572]: Plugin GPS
> [alias gps] loaded and initialized [
> INFO] [1423223050.870787476]: Plugin
> IMUPub [alias imu_pub] loaded and
> initialized [ INFO]
> [1423223050.870830161]: Plugin [alias
> local_position] blacklisted [ INFO]
> [1423223050.873211089]: Plugin Param
> [alias param] loaded and initialized [
> INFO] [1423223050.877987176]: Plugin
> RCIO [alias rc_io] loaded and
> initialized [ INFO]
> [1423223050.878022845]: Plugin [alias
> safety_area] blacklisted [ INFO]
> [1423223050.878043033]: Plugin [alias
> setpoint_accel] blacklisted [ INFO]
> [1423223050.878060355]: Plugin [alias
> setpoint_attitude] blacklisted [ INFO]
> [1423223050.878076733]: Plugin [alias
> setpoint_position] blacklisted [ INFO]
> [1423223050.878093765]: Plugin [alias
> setpoint_velocity] blacklisted [ INFO]
> [1423223050.885327432]: Plugin
> SystemStatus [alias sys_status] loaded
> and initialized [ INFO]
> [1423223050.888867617]: Plugin
> SystemTime [alias sys_time] loaded and
> initialized [ INFO]
> [1423223050.890337403]: Plugin VFRHUD
> [alias vfr_hud] loaded and initialized
> [ INFO] [1423223050.895379793]: Plugin
> Waypoint [alias waypoint] loaded and
> initialized [ INFO]
> [1423223050.895428569]: MAVROS
> started. MY ID [1, 240], TARGET ID [1,
> 1] [ERROR] [1423223052.700703044]:
> FCU: Calibrating barometer [ INFO]
> [1423223052.704659082]: CON: Got
> HEARTBEAT, connected. [ INFO]
> [1423223054.245342256]: FCU: barometer
> calibration complete [ INFO]
> [1423223054.253319191]: FCU: GROUND
> START [ INFO] [1423223062.721007722]:
> FCU: ArduCopter V3.2 (c8e0f3e1) [
> INFO] [1423223062.724986869]: FCU:
> Frame: Y6 [ INFO]
> [1423223067.726841955]: WP: mission
> received [ INFO]
> [1423223074.878456321]: PR: parameters
> list received

I receive messages from `/mavros/state`, but not from `/mavros/imu/data`

**ADDED**: I can receive messages after `~set_stream_rate` with max rate 13 for `/mavros/imu/data`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202593/mavros-with-serial-connection/) by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2015-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mavros don't change stream setup at startup. But usual it is not needed.

Also there is `mavsys` script, try do `mavsys rate --raw-sensors 10`.

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2015-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2015-02-07**:
I think that `rosrun mavros mavsys rate --all 30` is equal `rosservice call /mavros/set_stream_rate 0 30 1`, isn't it? But when I use the first one, I get maximum rate about 20 hz for `mavros/imu/data`... I don't understand why that happen.

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-02-07**:
Equal. Strange :)

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2015-02-08**:
What is maximum rate of `mavros/imu/data`?

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-02-08**:
Rate limited by FCU. With PX4 i got maximum ~150 Hz, and on some branches up to 200.

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2015-02-08**:
With apm2 I have maximum 25hz after `rosrun mavros mavsys rate --extra1 50` ...